# Reducing Webpack bundle size with braintree-web and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, web, webpack, braintree

Using braintree-web 3.61.0 with Vue.js 2.6.11 and TypeScript 3.8.3, I export the parts of braintree-web I need as a service like this:

```
import { client, hostedFields, applePay } from 'braintree-web';
export default { client , hostedFields, applePay };
```

Using webpack-bundle-analyzer, my builds appear to be pulling in all of 'braintree-web'. The code above produces the same result as:

```
import braintree from 'braintree-web';
export default braintree;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Braintree Technical Support confirmed this to be a problem with braintree-web 3.x. TypeScript support is coming in braintree-web 4.x.